# how to vertical align image in ul

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a vertical align for my `ul` element

I have something like

```
<ul id='menu'>
       <li><a href='index.html'><img class='vert' src='images/home.png' /></a>
      </li><img class='vert' src='images/vert2.png'/><li><a href='#'>project</a></li>
      <img class='vert' src='images/vert2.png'/>
      <li><a href='test.html'>test</a></li>
      <img class='vert' src='images/vert2.png'/>
     <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
     <img class='vert' src='images/vert2.png'/>
     <li><a href='#'>Numbers</a></li><img class='vert' src='images/vert2.png'/>
 </ul>
```

My css

```
nav #menu{
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
}

nav #menu .vert{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

nav #menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 42px;
    border-bottom:4px solid black;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

nav #menu li a{
   color: white;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font:normal 1.1em proxima-reg;
   margin: 0 10px;
   line-height: 46px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The first button is an image and the rest are texts. I was able to align the texts to the middle but I am not sure how to vertical align my image to middd. Currently the image is align to top.

Can anyone help me on this one? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/qS3R8/ "Fiddle Example") work for you?

Answer (score 2):

image should not be direct child of ul.

Make `<li>` , not `float` but `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align:middle`, and wrap image in `<li>` as well to have a correct code.

All `<li>` will vertical center themselves to each others.

Comment: the only problem i have is the home.png which is wrapped inside li tag. I also have display:inline-block and vertical-align:middle for my li element.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in a Div, then apply style="margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto;"